# a "marked as fixed" equivalent in Bing Webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console, url, bing-webmaster-tools

In GWT, in the report of pages producing error statuses (crawl errors), there is an option to label up to 1000 pages per day as "fixed" via the "marked as fixed" button.

I want to do this in Bing Webmaster Tools since some of their reports are inaccurate, but I'm unsure how. Any idea?

Comment: "some of their reports are inaccurate" - I'd still be reluctant to mark anything as fixed (if that is indeed possible) unless I had done something in the way to try and "fix it". _I think_ one reason why this feature might not be available in Bing tools is that the reports appear to relate to just the "last crawl". Whereas Google's reports contain historic data. (?)